# How can I remove the first doctype tooltip of the ace-editor in my html-editor?

Tags: javascript, html, ace-editor

We ask the user here to define html, so add a `div` or a section or something like that. So, I want the validation-tooltips when editing my HTML. But don't wanna have the doc-type warning.

[image: tooltip of ace editor]

Comment: As stated [in this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ace-discuss/qOVHhjhgpsU/E_34XjuMmlsJ), it doesn't seem to be possible to filter certain errors, though you can disable them all.

Answer (score 12):

Try this

```
var session = editor.getSession();
session.on("changeAnnotation", function() {
  var annotations = session.getAnnotations()||[], i = len = annotations.length;
  while (i--) {
    if(/doctype first\. Expected/.test(annotations[i].text)) {
      annotations.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  if(len>annotations.length) {
    session.setAnnotations(annotations);
  }
});
```

Comment: Almost works perfectly. In the event of a malformed tag in the first line, in addition to a "Unexpected end of file in the tag name", we also receive a `Unexpected End of File. Expected DOCTYPE.` - it's not really a big deal, but it would be great if you updated your snippet to reflect this. :)

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable len

Comment: The undeclared variable len is most likely because you're in strict mode. Declaring those variables explicity should clear the error. var annotations = this.aceEditor.session.getAnnotations()||[];
   let i = annotations.length; 
   let len = i;

Answer (score 3):

With "Unexpected End of File. Expected DOCTYPE." warning filtered.

```
var session = editor.getSession();
session.on("changeAnnotation", function () {
    var annotations = session.getAnnotations() || [], i = len = annotations.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (/doctype first\. Expected/.test(annotations[i].text)) {
            annotations.splice(i, 1);
        }
        else if (/Unexpected End of file\. Expected/.test(annotations[i].text)) {
            annotations.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    if (len > annotations.length) {
        session.setAnnotations(annotations);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If instead you operate on the `annotations` directly and call the editor `onChangeAnnotation` method directly to update the annotations on the page you can prevent firing another `changeAnnotation` event and calling this event handler twice as Chris's answer does.

```js
var editor = Application.ace.edit(element),
    session = editor.getSession();

session.on('changeAnnotation', function () {
  session.$annotations = session.$annotations.filter(function(annotation){
    return !(/doctype first\. Expected/.test(annotation.text) || /Unexpected End of file\. Expected/.test(annotation.text))
  });
  editor.$onChangeAnnotation();
});
```